# ¿Como Unir los registros que contengan el mismo dato?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
Select CONCAT(C.Nombre1,' ',C.Nombre2,' ',C.Apellido1,' ',C.Apellido2) as Nombre, 
DS.Poliza,
C.Telefono,
C.CentrodeTrabajo,
DS2.ClavePromo as Promotor, 
V.Descripcion, 
V.Año, 
P.FechaPago, 
P.Monto, 
P.Estado as Estado, 
P.NumPago, 
P.FechaTrajo,
T.Tarjeta, 
T.Vigencia, 
T.ID 
from CLIENTE C, DATOSSEGURO DS, DATOSSEGURO2 DS2, VEHICULO V, PAGOS P, TARJETAS T 
where C.NumCliente = DS.NumCliente 
and T.NumCliente=C.NumCliente 
and DS.NumPoliza = DS2.NumPoliza 
and C.NumCliente = V.NumCliente 
and V.SNum = DS.SNum 
and P.NumPoliza = DS.NumPoliza 
and P.FechaTrajo BETWEEN " + Fechas_Unidas2 + " 
and P.Est='NP' and P.Estado!='No Cobrar'
```

Me arroja por ejemplo, el siguiente resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me repite varias veces por que el cliente tiene varios pagos en una determinada fecha. Lo que necesito y ver si pueden ayudarme es que solo me salga una vez el cliente, con el monto total de cuanto pago (`P.Monto`),

Ejemplo...

`Concat Nombre`,`Poliza`, `Monto total`,`Pagos realizados`,etc

Jesus Daniel Vazquez Lorenzo,15080714,1000,1-2-3-4-5,...etc...

Intente implementarle el group by `DS.Poliza` pero me arroja error en el concat...

De antemano, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tengo duda con esto de aqui  BETWEEN " + Fechas_Unidas2 + "  te funciona asi, creo que eso marcaria error al menos que sea SQL Dinamico

Comment: Disculpa, es que es una variable que ocupo, esta guardar las dos fechas que el usuario ingrese. las manda desde una aplicacion en C#

Answer (score 1):

creo que podrías probar lo siguiente:

1. Crear una tabla consulta para los nombres:

```sql
FROM ..., Select CONCAT(CLIENTE.Nombre1,' ',CLIENTE.Nombre2,' ',CLIENTE.Apellido1,' ',CLIENTE.Apellido2) as Nombre, CLIENTE.NumCliente FROM CLIENTE N
```

2. Seleccionar, en vez de CONCAT, N.Nombre en la consulta principal

```sql
Select N.Nombre, 
DS.Poliza,
...
```

3. Mostrar la suma de los montos y agruapar por las columnas repetidas:

```sql
...,
P.FechaPago, 
SUM(P.Monto) AS Monto, 
P.Estado as Estado, 
...
GROUP BY DS.Poliza, C.Telefono, C.CentrodeTrabajo
```

Quedando algo como:

```sql
SELECT 
    N.Nombre, DS.Poliza,C.Telefono,C.CentrodeTrabajo,
    DS2.ClavePromo AS Promotor, V.Descripcion, V.Año, P.FechaPago, 
    SUM(P.Monto) AS Monto, 
    P.Estado AS Estado, P.NumPago, P.FechaTrajo,T.Tarjeta, T.Vigencia, T.ID 
FROM CLIENTE C, DATOSSEGURO DS, DATOSSEGURO2 DS2, VEHICULO V, PAGOS P, TARJETAS T, 
     SELECT CONCAT(CLIENTE.Nombre1,' ',CLIENTE.Nombre2,' ',CLIENTE.Apellido1,' ',CLIENTE.Apellido2) AS Nombre, CLIENTE.NumCliente FROM CLIENTE N
WHERE C.NumCliente = DS.NumCliente 
    AND T.NumCliente=C.NumCliente 
    AND DS.NumPoliza = DS2.NumPoliza 
    AND C.NumCliente = N.NumCliente 
    AND C.NumCliente = V.NumCliente 
    AND V.SNum = DS.SNum 
    AND P.NumPoliza = DS.NumPoliza 
    AND P.FechaTrajo BETWEEN " + Fechas_Unidas2 + " 
    AND P.Est='NP' AND P.Estado!='No Cobrar'
GROUP BY DS.Poliza, C.Telefono, C.CentrodeTrabajo
```

Comment: Mme marca error de Sintaxis en el Select (creo que en el segundo, del FROM)

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Al final lo deje como le tenia en un principio solo ya no concateno el nombre por que es el que no me deja... Puedo darte la respuesta por correcta igualmente, solo me gustaria que me apoyaras en que si sabes como colocar por ejemplo que en el Numero de pagos no sea Count() si no que me arroje que pagos son (3,4,5,8) en vez de (4).

Comment: Creo que puedes utilizar `GROUP_CONCAT(P.NumPago ORDER BY P.NumPoliza)`.

Comment: Buscando un poco la respuesta correcta es la siguiente: STRING_AGG(P.NumPago,',') WITHIN GROUP(order by convert(int,P.NumPago)) as Num_Pago. Pero igualmente Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de cambiar la sintaxis de unión de las tablas, ya que esta obsoleta.

Aparte de ese matiz, lo que solicitas es utilizar funciones de agrupación, para algunas columnas.

```
Select CONCAT(c.nombre1, ' ', c.nombre2, ' ', c.apellido1, ' ', c.apellido2) As nombre
     , ds.poliza
     , c.telefono
     , c.centrodetrabajo
     , ds2.clavepromo As promotor
     , v.descripcion
     , v.año
     , Max(p.fechapago) As ultimopago
     , Sum(p.monto) As total
     , p.estado As estado
     , Count(p.numpago) As pagos
     , p.fechatrajo As fechatrabajo
     , t.tarjeta
     , t.vigencia
     , t.id
       From cliente As c
            Inner Join datosseguro As ds On c.numcliente = ds.numcliente
            Inner Join datosseguro2 As ds2 On ds.numpoliza = ds2.numpoliza
            Inner Join vehiculo As v On v.snum = ds.snum And c.numcliente = v.numcliente
            Inner Join pagos As p On p.numpoliza = ds.numpoliza
            Inner Join tarjetas As t On t.numcliente = c.numcliente
       Where     p.fechatrajo Between " + Fechas_Unidas2 + " 
            And  p.est = 'NP' 
            And  p.estado <> 'No Cobrar'
       Group By c.nombre1
              , c.nombre2
              , c.apellido1
              , c.apellido2
              , ds.poliza
              , c.telefono
              , c.centrodetrabajo
              , ds2.clavepromo
              , v.descripcion
              , v.año
              , p.estado
              , p.fechatrajo
              , t.tarjeta
              , t.vigencia
              , t.id;
```

Si observas la solución que te planteo, lo único que cambia es, que la columna fechaPago, solo obtenemos un valor para poder reducir las filas, y nos quedamos con el último, la columna monto, sumamos las cantidades, y la columna numpago contamos el número de ellas que contiene.

Es posible que haya que hacer algún retoque más, ya que en la imagen no se muestran los datos y por tanto  haya que implementar alguna función de agrupación más para alguna columna.

[Group by la cláusula más conflictiva](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/)